# How to update multiple selections of a listbox, in different rows of a nvarchar() column in database?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, listbox

I have a dropdowncheckbox consisting of several userid's. Now on selecting a user it will display 2 listboxes, Listbox1 has a list of barcodes and Listbox2  contains barcodes already assigned to the user. From listbox1 multiple items need to be selected and assigned to the user.Now I want to update the selected userid  column against the selected barcodes. Each barcode is in a different row in the database . I tried:

```
protected void assign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            Label9.Text = "Please Select Barcodes";
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected == true)
                {
                    ListBox2.Items.Add(item);
                    ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch { //Some code }
    finally
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con"].ConnectionString);

        string cmdtxt= "Update " + con.Database + " set AssgnId= @userid where barcode= @barcode ";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdtxt,con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", ddchkteachers2.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", ListBox1.SelectedItem);

        con.Open();

        foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected == true)
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@barcode"].Value = Convert.ToString(ListBox1.SelectedItem);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        } 
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

The selected  barcodes are in a nvarchar()column in the database. How to convert? the current value in the userid column against the barcodes are Null. Code does'nt update .

Comment: Your update statement is wrong, instead of con.Database, mention the table name because its a database connection string which is coming from your `web.config`.

Comment: That should not be a problem cause its being generated dynamically.

Comment: Firstly, give your server control a proper name through which they can be identified easily what you have followed is a bad coding practice. Next, while saving the value in database either use `ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text` or `ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value`. BTW can you explain what is **con.Database** in your update query.

Comment: Still not working.. @Supra

Comment: In your post you have mentioned barcode can be selected multiple times but your DB architecture seems to be wrong as you are updating a single field. This doesn't make any sense. What you are trying to is to perform one - one relationship but what you are trying to achieve is one - many relationship this barcode should be kept in a separated table.

Comment: I did try ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value but it gives nullRefrenceExcptn hence i was trying cmd.Parameters["@barcode"].Value =  Convert.ToString(ListBox1.SelectedItem). And thats what i am asking in the question. I have used connection string to pass the DB as code will be generating several DB's .So this is for the current DB instance .

Comment: Sorry this is a little complicated . see ..in my database i have a barcode column and a userid column .. so basically all selected barcodes from the list need to be updated with the choosen userid...if that makes sense

Comment: Slight deviation from the question, but a good read about Paramerters such as `.AddWithValue` compared to `.Add`

http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing Items from `ListBox1` in first `loop` by checking whether they are selected or not and in the second `loop` you are doing same thing. It means there will be no value within your `ListBox1` within 2nd loop. You can put a `breakpoint` within the loop and verify its values.

When the statement executes,

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", ListBox1.SelectedItem);
```

There is nothing within your `ListBox1.SelectedItem`, same is the case within your foreach loop.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I realized the blunder..thank you for pointing out. It works fine now..